# 301 redirect with wildcard in htaccess not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

All traffic will be directed from

```
https://oldsite.com/
```

to

```
https://www.newsite.com
```

I am looking for a 301 wildcard redirect solution for the following

```
https://oldsite.com/blog/*(the slug)
```

to

```
https://www.newsite.com/blog/*(matching slug)
```

Used htaccess file is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do share your htaccess Rules file in your question, thank you.

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following. Keep your domain redirection at the top of your htaccess file then keep other Rules. Also make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

##Have your domain changes rules here...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^  https://www.newsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

##Non existing files/directories rewrite rules here.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```